# Kendo grid max height with scrolling (virtual)

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I found that you can add some css to both the k-grid-content and the k-virtual-scrollable-wrap.  They have to be the same max-height.

```
.k-grid-content {
   max-height: 300px;
}

.k-virtual-scrollable-wrap {
    max-height: 300px
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: this is not a question, its a answer to the question. I did not know how to show the answer to a question.  I thought my answer would be useful for a lot of people.